# App start with NullPointerException on device

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crash

I made a fresh build (after the weekend) and my app crashed with the exception below. The interesting part is, that I made a build last week with the same configuration without any code changes and it worked then. The app works well on emulator, but on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 throws exception.
I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1. Is somebody faced with a same issue?

```
12-21 14:19:27.359 6142-6142/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                 at android.view.View.getHardwareLayer(View.java:10225)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2863)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10462)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10462)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11028)
                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10464)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11028)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10464)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10462)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10462)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10462)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10462)
                                                 at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:840)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1923)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1647)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2459)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did you try to clean the project and uninstall the app from the device before reinstalling?

Comment: Also make sure that you didn't specify layout for tablet. If you did it, make sure that it has appropriate views.

Comment: I made a clean install, deleted the app from the device befor the new install (with a project clean).
The app don't have any specified layouts for tablet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem, but I don't know why is it exactly working. I increased the version of the `android v4 support library` from `23.0.0` to `23.1.1` and the app didn't crashed.

Comment: I was receiving this same crash with AdMob from Google Play Services 8.4.0. It seems it is also using the buggy version of support lib. Switching to GPS v8.1.0 fixes the issue completely. Really garbage from Google. Disappointing. Your answer gave me some hope that it wasn't my code causing the crash.